# How to manually edit a JSON object storec in a String column in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, string, parse-platform, stringify

I have a column in the **String** type. I would like to store my data in a JSON string in the column but still be able to edit manually in the table view on the Parse.com dashboard.

The cloud code uses the following code snippet in "Parse.Cloud.beforeSave" to stringify the javascript object.

```
var sharedByArr = [];
sharedByArr.push({"st":"VIC","sh":true});
sharedByArr.push({"st":"QLD","sh":true});
sharedByArr.push({"st":"NSW","sh":true});

var myObj = {
        "bindings" : sharedByArr
    }
JSON.stringify(myObj)
```

The string stored in the column is:

```
{"bindings":[{"st":"VIC","sh":true},{"st":"QLD","sh":true},{"st":"NSW","sh":true}]}
```

The issue is that I was not able to manually edit the JSON string in the column. Any change I made to the string (e.g. change a Boolean value) was immediately lost even if the dashboard said "Successfully updated the object." How can I edit manually the JSON object stored in a String column in Parse.com.

Comment: immediately lost how? the web view didn't show it update?

Comment: Well. It was updated but in one or half a second the change was lost and the string was restored.

Comment: so you need to work out what did that, presumably some code you have running somewhere. if not then talk to parse about a potential bug with their web interface

Comment: I think the problem is "beforeSave" applied to new a table row.

Comment: so this isn't a programming question without telling us that and showing the code... If you have validation there then you can't make a change without considering that validation